# Step #0 - "Build": Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat '//proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vite

Docker file running on compute engine.
Can anyone figure out this issue.

```
error during build:
Step #0 - "Build": Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat '//proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/proc/1/map_files/5583c9161000-5583c9165000'
Step #0 - "Build":     at Object.statSync (fs.js:1132:3)
Step #0 - "Build":     at Object.stat (/node_modules/recrawl-sync/lib/fs.js:10:22)
Step #0 - "Build":     at crawl (/node_modules/recrawl-sync/lib/recrawl.js:55:31)
Step #0 - "Build":     at crawl (/node_modules/recrawl-sync/lib/recrawl.js:70:29)
Step #0 - "Build":     at crawl (/node_modules/recrawl-sync/lib/recrawl.js:70:29)
Step #0 - "Build":     at crawl (/node_modules/recrawl-sync/lib/recrawl.js:70:29)
Step #0 - "Build":     at crawl (/node_modules/recrawl-sync/lib/recrawl.js:70:29)
Step #0 - "Build":     at crawl (/node_modules/recrawl-sync/lib/recrawl.js:70:29)
Step #0 - "Build":     at crawl (/node_modules/recrawl-sync/lib/recrawl.js:70:29)
Step #0 - "Build":     at crawl (/node_modules/recrawl-sync/lib/recrawl.js:70:29)
Step #0 - "Build": npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Step #0 - "Build": npm ERR! errno 1
Step #0 - "Build": npm ERR! goodmeetings@0.1.0 build: `tsc && vite build`
Step #0 - "Build": npm ERR! Exit status 1
Step #0 - "Build": npm ERR! 
Step #0 - "Build": npm ERR! Failed at the go
```

modification on the docker files, but none of them are working

Comment: That filename argument for stat is huge. More than likely, that is an invalid path. are you certain that `//proc/1/cwd/proc/1/cwd/...` is a valid resource? Regardless,`EPERM` is thrown which is a permissions issue. What user is your Dockerfile specifying? You should give that user admin, or use an admin user.

Answer (score 0):

use `WORKDIR /app` instead of `WORKDIR /` in the config